# Array store the same value in React?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Code:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

 const handleClick = (val, id) => {
        setActiveIndex(id);          
        let text = val;
        let index = id;
        setItem([...item, { val: text, index: index }]);
        // console.log("text", text);     
       };
```

Button code:-

```
<div>
                {ChannelName.map((val, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="TextLink" key={index}>
                            <NavLink to={`/Table`}
                                onClick={(e) => myClick(val, index)} >
                                <button className='notActive buttonLeft'
                                    onClick={() => { handleOnClick(index); handleClick(val, index) }} // pass the index                                       
                                    className={activeIndex === index ? "active" : "notActive"}>
                                    {val}
                                </button>
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                }
            </div>
```

Tab div:-

```
 <div className="allDivs">
            {item.map((items, index) => {
                console.log(item)
                return (
                    <div key={index} >
                        <Test item={items} index={index} activeIndex={activeIndex} />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
```

When I click the Rundown List it's one time store but when I click the same value the second time it stores the same value
How can I stop that value to store in the second click?

tab component:-

```
export default function Test({ item, index, activeIndex }) {
    const [Close, setClose] = useState(true) // Every Child now has it's own setClose controll


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div  id="CLOSEDIV" style={{ display: Close ? '' : 'none' }}   className={activeIndex === index ? "activeTAB" : "tableHeaderBody"}>
                <div className="TableText">
                      <div id="SHOW">{item.val}</div></div>
                <div className="CloseIcon" id="CloseBtn"><FaRegTimesCircle style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "10px", height: "10px", alignItems: "right" }} onClick={() => { setClose(false) }} /></div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>

    )
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details and the related code. Where do you want to store data? Local storage? Generally speaking you could check wherever you store the value if it's already stored, and if it is not, store it.

Comment: waht are you expecting?

Comment: when I click the rundown list name(BUSINESS NEWS) in image its create the same name div but when I click the 2 time (BUSINESS NEWS) its create the 2 div with same name so i want to stop that 2 div .  setItem use state which store the every onclick value and then i map the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your objective is to prevent adding an item into an array if it already exists & this needs to be implemented in the method: `handleClick`, please try if the below code-sample helps.

```
const handleClick = (val, id) => {
  setItem(prev => {
    if (prev.some(({index}) => (id === index))) return prev;
    else return [...prev, {val, id}];
  });
  setActiveIndex(id);
};
```

**Explanation**

- Check if `prev` (ie, previous value of `item` state-variable
- already has `some` element where `index` prop matches `id`
- If so, simply ignore the current event's `val`, `id`
- Else, append a new object with `val` and `id` props into the array
- Update activeIndex (same as earlier case)